# Show that $XY$ is also symmetric.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables and $Y$ is symmetric. Show that $XY$ is also symmetric.

Honestly I have very little knowledge on Probability, so I have no clear idea on how to do this.

My poor try so far, $P(XY\leq t)=\int P(Y\leq t/x)f_X(x)dx=\int P(Y\geq -t/x)f_X(x)dx$. Am I on the right track? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about when $X$ is negative?

Comment: Hmm good question. So I have to consider negative positive separately right?

Comment: That, or don't divide and assert that $\mathsf P(xY\leq t)~{=\mathsf P(x(-Y)\geq -t)\\=\mathsf P(xY\geq -t)}$ for any constant values $x,t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, with the proviso that you account for behaviour when $X<0$.

Easiest not to divide and assert that the symmetric distribution means: $\mathsf P(aY\leq b)=\mathsf P(aY\geq -b)$

$$\mathsf P(XY\leqslant t) ~{ = \int_X \mathsf P(xY\leqslant t) f_X(x)\mathrm d x \qquad\text{by independence}
\\ = \int_X \mathsf P(xY\geqslant -t) f_X(x)\mathrm d x\qquad\text{by symmetry of }Y
\\ = \mathsf P(XY\geqslant -t)}$$